# InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. (.net core 5)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, openapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I use .net 5 web api to create my application.
I put [Authorize] top of my controller.
I use Identityserver4 as auth-server.(localhost:5000)
and here is my startup.cs class:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opts =>
            opts.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDb"));

        services.AddAuthentication("bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(opts =>
            {
                opts.Authority = "http://locallhost:5000";
                opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                opts.ApiName = "myApi";
            });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CustomerApi", Version = "v1" });
        });

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CustomerApi v1"));
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

but I get below error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaZAH.png)

please guide me to resolve my problem.
I search much time but the answers is for .net 3.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok.
but you should write:

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
```

instead of

```
 services.AddAuthentication("bearer")
```

After that you might run correctly.

Comment: What is Bearer in here ?

Answer (score 0):

I typically have this setup:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

I would also not use **AddIdentityServerAuthentication** (Used by older version of IdentityServer) and instead focus on using **AddJwtBearer** method instead. See the documentation [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/apis/aspnetcore/jwt/)

Comment: when using app.UseAuthorization() before app.UseRouting(), it warnings "Warning ASP0001 The call to UseAuthorization should appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(..) for authorization to be correctly evaluated."

Comment: yes, my misstake, I posted a sample pipeline that I typically use in my appliations.